# adding some text via php to change the name of mysqli requested object

Tags: php

I have this code which is ok

```
$row->main_auto_make_make
```

But I want to make something like this

```
$ride_type="auto";
$row->main_."$ride_type"._make_make
```

But this does not work. 
Instead of printing real data I get only `auto_make_make` text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
$row->{'main_'.$ride_type.'_make_make'}
```

see http://php.net/variables.variable